# create and append to blob storage using logic apps

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which polls for files does some things with them, succeeds or fails then ends.  It will run every 5 minutes and poll for a file.
If it finds a file I can create a blob storage with a date time suffix eg LogutcNow('s').txt
I want to append to this file various messages generated from the logic app eg if steps succeed or fail.

Is Blob storage the best way to put a file in my Azure storage account?
Since the name of the blob depends on the date time, how do I append to it?
It may be that the logic app does not write anything to the log file. In that case I want to delete it.

[image]

I want to create the blob at the beginning of my logic app then update it.  If there are no updates then I want to delete it.  In the update action it seems to require me to specify the name of the blob.  Since I haven't create the blob yet this is impossible.  One thing I also tried was initialising a string variable to the current date and time and putting that variable into the filename.

[image]

Comment: So what problem did you encounter?  What exception or other problem you got when you run your flow?

Comment: When I try to update my blob, it gives the name of the blob it finds in the directory.  Since the name varies with each run of the logic app, this won't work.

Comment: So you want to update blob not create blob? If could please paste a detailed or the error flow image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your main problem is after you create a blob with dynamic name and could not get the blob name to do other actions. If that you could just set the blob name with dynamic content Path, if it doesn't shown the dynamic content just set the expression `body('Create_blob')?['Path']`.

[image]

Comment: Another idea could be to put the filename into a string variable and reference that variable.  Thanks very much.